# How to handle custom exception in Asp.Net Core Web API in server

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple asp.net core 3.1 web api application and CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware. Everything works good in my local computer but when I host(inProcess hosting model) my project under IIS api doesnt return my exceptions. Here is sample code:

```
    public async Task<string> PostTestAsync(TestRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Key == "exception")
        {
            throw new BusinessException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Post Test exception");
        }
        var response = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return $"Post {request.Key}";
        });
        return response;
    }
```

When I send to request.Key = "exception" app returns "Connection ID "{ConnectionId}", Request ID "{TraceIdentifier}": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.".

But when I send different from "exception" works fine.

Here is my CustomExceptionMiddleware:

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);

            var code = exception is BusinessException ? (exception as BusinessException).StatusCode : HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;

            var apiResponse = new MyApiResponse
            {
                IsSuccess = false,
                ErrorResponse = new ErrorResponse
                {
                    Type = exception.GetType().ToString(),
                    StatusCode = (int)code,
                    Message = exception.Message,
                    StackTrace = exception.StackTrace
                }
            };

            var jApiResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(jApiResponse);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solve the problem. My Startup class was like this:

```
if(env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseMyExceptionHandler();
```

So in server; environment is not development and when I throw any exception myMiddleware didnt catch it and App return InternalServerError. I also added `env.IsProduction()` condition and everything solved.